# SSRS 2005 Previous sum of date and time

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have an SSRS report which when I try to calculate the previous value the first line always gives incorrect value since there is no previous number for it to calculate.

```
=CDec(format(DateDiff("s",previous(Fields!SyncDate.Value),Fields!Date.Value)/60,"0.00"))
```

The value of the first line comes out 1059831848.62
Is there a way to tell it to skip first line?
Because also i need to sum it all to get total which counts the first line and gives a huge total.

My query consists of the following:

```
SELECT ToppingCount, DriverName, COUNT(Pizza) AS Count, Date, SyncDate, BranchName, Branch
FROM System
WHERE     (Date BETWEEN @datefrom AND @DateTo) AND (Branch IN (@branch)) AND (SystemSource = 'newsys') AND (SystemSource <> 'oldsys')
GROUP BY Pizza, ToppingCount, DriverName, Date, SyncDate, BranchName, Branch
ORDER BY Branch, DriverName, Date
```

Thanks

Comment: A combination of `iif()` and `isNothing()` perhaps? Or create a dummy first row in your query and union with your existing select?

Comment: not exactly sure on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of the previous sync date field and output a 0 or blank if required.

```
=CDec(iif(IsNothing(previous(Fields!SyncDate.Value)), 0.0, format(DateDiff("s",previous(Fields!SyncDate.Value),Fields!Date.Value)/60,"0.00")))
```

Without row_number you can use an outer apply to get the last sync date in the query and pre-calculate the 'sync delta':

```
SELECT
    p.ToppingCount, 
    p.DriverName,
    p.Date,
    p.SyncDate,
    CASE
        WHEN i.SynchDate IS NULL THEN 0.0
        ELSE DATEDIFF(SS, l.SyncDate, p.Date) / 60.0
    END AS SyncTimeDelta,
    p.BranchName,
    p.Branch,
    COUNT(p.Pizza) AS Count
FROM System p
OUTER APPLY
(
    -- Join clause depends on how you're grouping
    -- in the report.
    SELECT TOP 1
        i.SyncDate
    FROM System i
    WHERE
        i.SystemSource = 'newsys'
        AND i.Branch = p.Branch
        AND i.DriverName = p.DriverName
        AND i.Date < p.Date
    ORDER BY
        i.SyncDate DESC
) l
WHERE
    (p.Date BETWEEN @datefrom AND @DateTo) AND
(p.Branch IN (@branch)) AND
    (p.SystemSource = 'newsys') AND
    (p.SystemSource <> 'oldsys')    -- This will never be evaluated
GROUP BY
    p.Pizza, p.ToppingCount, p.DriverName, p.Date, p.SyncDate, p.BranchName, p.Branch, l.SyncDate
ORDER BY
    p.Branch, p.DriverName, p.Date
```

This way you can just sum the sync delta in the report. I don't know enough about the query but I've made the assumption that:

You want the time between the last sync date before the current [date] column as per your formula for the given branch and driver.

I apologize if there are syntax issues, I'm typing this up without reference.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I have tried this and got 0. will try to play around with this more.

Comment: If you want a blank field you can place the if statement outside, change the 0.0 to "" and put the calculation (including the decimal conversion) in side the else part of the iif.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Row_Number column to your query like so..

```
SELECT  ToppingCount,
        DriverName,
        COUNT(Pizza) AS Count,
        Date,
        SyncDate,
        BranchName,
        Branch,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Branch,DriverName,Date) Rn
FROM    System
WHERE   (Date BETWEEN @datefrom AND @DateTo)
        AND (Branch IN (@branch))
        AND (SystemSource = 'newsys')
        AND (SystemSource <> 'oldsys')
GROUP BY Pizza,
        ToppingCount,
        DriverName,
        Date,
        SyncDate,
        BranchName,
        Branch
ORDER BY Branch,
        DriverName,
        Date
```

Then just check to see if you are on Rn = 1 before you do your calculation.

```
=iif(Fields!Rn.Value = 1, "", CDec(format(DateDiff("s",previous(Fields!SyncDate.Value),Fields!Date.Value)/60,"0.00")))
```

or

```
=iif(Fields!Rn.Value = 1, 0, CDec(format(DateDiff("s",previous(Fields!SyncDate.Value),Fields!Date.Value)/60,"0.00")))
```

if you need to reset the Row_Number for groupings, you can add Partition By to reset the number to 1

Comment: Awesome will have a go at that

Comment: Just tried it and it says "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported." but when I run the report it runs but gives -465

Comment: Hmm.. Are you running sql 2005 or greater ?

Comment: yeah stuck with 2005

Comment: I kinda found another way around this formula but when I try to sum it I get an error. 
=(Last(Fields!SyncDate.Value))-(First(Fields!Date.Value))-TimeSpan.FromTicks(sum(Fields!SyncDate.Value-Fields!Date.Value)))
even tried to =sum(reportitem!textbox12.value) but still get error as well